# Spring Data Jpa (with H2) exception on save with OneToMany

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have simple Spring Boot app with in-memory H2 database, and I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DictEntity{
    @Id
    Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    String name;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ComplexEntity {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @Column
    String name;

    @Column
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<DictEntity> properties;
}
```

Hibernate generates me such DDL:

```
Hibernate: create table complex_entity (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table complex_entity_entities (complex_entity_id bigint not null, entities_id bigint not null)
Hibernate: create table dict_entity (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table complex_entity_entities add constraint UK_nxr507qlfqwm2vk6gqes2b3lc unique (entities_id)
Hibernate: alter table dict_entity add constraint UK_m9sbjtymc6urpykp5ko3faep1 unique (name)
Hibernate: alter table complex_entity_entities add constraint FKn66943skv39n53nfkj6wwsnl2 foreign key (entities_id) references dict_entity
Hibernate: alter table complex_entity_entities add constraint FK6wqn8as4rkbi5caulfyex6sxm foreign key (complex_entity_id) references complex_entity
```

And then I have a code:

```
foo = anEntityRepository.save(new DictEntity(1L, "foo"));
bar = anEntityRepository.save(new DictEntity(2L, "bar"));
ComplexEntity m1 = complexEntityRepository.save(new ComplexEntity(1l, "m1", Collections.singletonList(foo)));
ComplexEntity m2 = complexEntityRepository.save(new ComplexEntity(2l, "m2", Collections.singletonList(foo)));
```

On last line i got an Exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UK_NXR507QLFQWM2VK6GQES2B3LC_INDEX_9 ON PUBLIC.COMPLEX_ENTITY_ENTITIES(ENTITIES_ID) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
insert into complex_entity_entities (complex_entity_id, entities_id) values (?, ?)
```

What went wrong?

Comment: `save(new ComplexEntity(2l, "m2", Collections.singletonList(foo)));` you save `foo` a second time there, but it already exists from the first save. And on that id column there is a unique constraint `alter table complex_entity_entities add constraint UK_nxr507qlfqwm2vk6gqes2b3lc unique (entities_id)`. That is why you generally create tables manually, so that hibernate doesn't generate useless stuff. Reason for the generated useless stuff is the fact, that the relationship is uni-directional.

Comment: If you add `@ManyToOne(mappedBy = "properties") ComplexEntity complexEntity` to `DictEntity` it should work fine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer but I don't want bidirectional one2many, I need exactly one-directional relationship between these entities

Comment: Then create the tables manually or just drop the unique constraint. As said, hibernate will generate this the same way over and over unless you change the mapping.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'd removed "unique", but H2 still throws that exception.

Comment: which unique did you remove?

Comment: One possible thing to do is: remove the OneToMany annotation, change it to Transient annotation, and add the ManyToOne annotation in DictEntity class. Then you need to add the ComplexEntity first, then the DictEntity. After that, you fill your list of DictEntity using findAllByComplexEntity() method you're going to create in your ComplexEntityRepository.

Answer (score 0):

Your error

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PUBLIC.UK_NXR507QLFQWM2VK6GQES2B3LC_INDEX_9 ON PUBLIC.COMPLEX_ENTITY_ENTITIES(ENTITIES_ID) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:
insert into complex_entity_entities (complex_entity_id, entities_id) values (?, ?)
```

has nothing to do with what you suspect in the question as a cause, as you mention the

```
@Column
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<DictEntity> properties;
```

Probably the

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ComplexEntity {
   ...
```

has also another field which is used to create the mapping table `complex_entity_entities` and this is the one that is failing.

Update the question with all relevant code to find exactly the issue. I expect that you have a field named `entities` upon `ComplexEntity.class`.

I suspect though that the `ComplexEntity` has reference upon other `ComplexEntity` and this is the type of issue here.